# Perl search for first occurrence of pattern in directory

Tags: perl, grep

I have a directory with a list of image header files of the format

```
image1.hd
image2.hd
image3.hd
image4.hd
```

I want to search for the regular expression `Image type:=4` in the directory and find the file number which has the first occurrence of this pattern. I can do this with a couple of pipes easily in bash:

```
 grep -l 'Image type:=4' image*.hd | sed ' s/.*image\(.*\).hd/\1/' | head -n1
```

which returns 1 in this case.

This pattern match will be used in a perl script. I know I could use

```
my $number = `grep -l 'Image type:=4' image*.hd | sed ' s/.*image\(.*\).hd/\1/' | head -n1`
```

but is it preferable to use pure perl in such cases? Here is the best I could come up with using perl. It is very cumbersome:

```
my $tmp;
#want to find the planar study in current study
  foreach (glob "$DIR/image*.hd"){
    $tmp = $_;
    open FILE, "<", "$_" or die $!;
    while (<FILE>)
      {
    if (/Image type:=4/){
      $tmp =~ s/.*image(\d+).hd/$1/;
    }
      }
    close FILE;
    last;
  }
 print "$tmp\n";
```

this also returns the desired output of 1. Is there a more effective way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simple with the help of a couple of utility modules

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Slurp 'read_file';
use List::MoreUtils 'firstval';

print firstval { read_file($_) =~ /Image type:=4/ } glob "$DIR/image*.hd";
```

But if you are restricted to core Perl, then this will do what you want

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $firstfile;
while (my $file = glob 'E:\Perl\source\*.pl') {
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;
    local $/;
    if ( <$fh> =~ /Image type:=4/) {
        $firstfile = $file;
        last;
    }
}

print $firstfile // 'undef';
```